# Поиск ближайшей точки

Tags: алгоритм, математика, структуры-данных

Есть множество точек A {(x<sub>l</sub>, y<sub>l</sub>)}. Нужно для некоторой точки (x, y) найти ближайшую точку из A. Как это оптимально сделать? Полный перебор не хочется

Comment: https://lsreg.ru/realizaciya-algoritma-poiska-a-na-c/

Comment: предрасчеты допустимы? если да - разложите множество в kd-дерево или в квадродерево на крайний случай

Comment: А что известно о точках? Если они как-то упорядочены - еще можно подумать... А в общем случае алгоритм O(N) - это вполне нормальное решение. Если вам надо будет делать такой поиск много-много раз - дело другое, можно переупорядочивать их. Но если вычисление разовое - то перебор будет самым быстрым.

Comment: @Harry вот их и хочется как-то упорядочить. Потому что поисков будет много

Comment: Тогда см. совет @StrangerintheQ...

Comment: @TEA Это алгоритм поиска кратчайшего пути. Это немного не то

Comment: "Потому что поисков будет много" - это должно было быть указано в тексте вопроса. И "много" в каком смысле? Много изолированных единичных поисков? Или поиски в которых много тестовых точек известны заранее?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Я почему-то понял вопрос не правильно и подумал про **N ближайших точек**. Как уже ответил **господин @AnT** [разбиение Вороного](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE) для этого намного лучше подойдет, собрал пример на d3.js в котором реализовано [разбиение Вороного](https://github.com/d3/d3-voronoi):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<style>body{margin:0}</style>
<script>
const voronoiRadius = 33;
const width = 600;
const height = 170;
const data = d3.range(333).map((d, i) => ({
  x: Math.random() * width,
  y: Math.random() * height,
  id: i
}));
const container = d3.select('body');
const svg = container.append('svg')
                     .attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
const g = svg.append('g');
const circles = g.append('g').attr('class', 'circles');
const binding = circles.selectAll('.data-point').data(data, d => d.id);

binding.enter().append('circle')
               .classed('data-point', true)
               .attr('r', 1.5)
               .attr('cx', d => d.x)
               .attr('cy', d => d.y)
               .attr('fill', 'blue');

const voronoiDiagram = d3.voronoi()
                         .x(d => d.x).y(d => d.y)
                         .size([width, height])(data);

g.append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'highlight-circle')
  .attr('r', 4) 
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('display', 'none');

function highlight(d) {
  if (!d) {
    d3.select('.highlight-circle').style('display', 'none');
  } else {
    d3.select('.highlight-circle')
      .style('display', '')
      .style('stroke', 'red')
      .attr('cx', d.x)
      .attr('cy', d.y);
  }
}

g.append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'voronoi-radius-circle')
    .attr('r', voronoiRadius)
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .style('stroke', 'tomato')
    .style('stroke-dasharray', '3,2')
    .style('display', 'none');

g.append('g').selectAll('path')
    .data(voronoiDiagram.polygons())
    .enter().append('path')
    .style('stroke', 'red')
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .style('opacity', 0.2)
    .attr('d', d => `M${d.join('L')}Z`);

container.on('mousemove', function () {
  const [mx, my] = d3.mouse(this);
  const site = voronoiDiagram.find(mx, my, voronoiRadius);
  highlight(site && site.data);
  d3.select('.voronoi-radius-circle')
        .style('display', '')
        .attr('cx', mx)
        .attr('cy', my);
}).on('mouseleave', () => {
    d3.select('.voronoi-radius-circle').style('display', 'none');
    highlight(null)
});
</script>
```

---

**Для поиска нескольких точек можно воспользоваться деревьями**

---

Есть [квадродерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) алгоритмы на нем достаточно просты и есть готовые реализации.

Вот пример использования [d3-quadtree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4343214) от [автора d3.js](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock)

> желтые - узлы которые обошел алгоритм поиска
>
> красные - найденные ближайшие узлы узлы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    selected;

var random = Math.random,
    data = d3.range(250).map(()=> [random() * width, random() * height]);

var quadtree = d3.quadtree()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .addAll(data);

var brush = d3.brush()
    .on("brush", brushed);

svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes(quadtree))
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x0; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y0; })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; });

var point = svg.selectAll(".point")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d[0]; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d[1]; })
    .attr("r", 2);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, [[100, 100], [200, 200]]);

function brushed() {
  var extent = d3.event.selection;
  point.each(function(d) { d.scanned = d.selected = false; });
  search(quadtree, extent[0][0], extent[0][1], extent[1][0], extent[1][1]);
  point.classed("point--scanned", function(d) { return d.scanned; });
  point.classed("point--selected", function(d) { return d.selected; });
}

function search(quadtree, x0, y0, x3, y3) {
  quadtree.visit(function(node, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    if (!node.length) {
      do {
        var d = node.data;
        d.scanned = true;
        d.selected = (d[0] >= x0) && (d[0] < x3) && (d[1] >= y0) && (d[1] < y3);
      } while (node = node.next);
    }
    return x1 >= x3 || y1 >= y3 || x2 < x0 || y2 < y0;
  });
}


function nodes(quadtree) {
  var nodes = [];
  quadtree.visit(function(node, x0, y0, x1, y1) {
    node.x0 = x0, node.y0 = y0;
    node.x1 = x1, node.y1 = y1;
    nodes.push(node);
  });
  return nodes;
}
```

```css
body {
overflow:hidden;
}

.point {
  fill: #000;
  fill-opacity: 0.4;
}

.point--scanned {
  fill: orange;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke: orange;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.point--selected {
  fill: red;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}

.node {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="700" height="175"></svg>
```

---

Вот пример испольлзующий [kd-дерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) и [поиск ближайших соседей из этого примера на d3.v3](https://bl.ocks.org/armollica/1593f53c0c8346d067491f39255d0b84) под последнюю версию `d3.v5`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
/// kd-tree.js

function BPQ(capacity) {
  this.capacity = capacity;
  this.elements = [];
}

BPQ.prototype.isFull = function() { 
  return this.elements.length === this.capacity; 
};

BPQ.prototype.isEmpty = function() { 
  return this.elements.length === 0; 
};

BPQ.prototype.maxPriority = function() {
  return this.elements[this.elements.length - 1].priority;
};

Object.defineProperty(BPQ.prototype, "values", {
  get: function() { return this.elements.map(function(d) { return d.value; }); }
});

BPQ.prototype.add = function(value, priority) {
  var q = this.elements,
      d = { value: value, priority: priority };
  if (this.isEmpty()) { q.push(d); } 
  else {
    for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
      if (priority < q[i].priority) {
        q.splice(i, 0, d);
        break;
      }
      else if ( (i == q.length-1) && !this.isFull() ) {
        q.push(d);
      }
    }
  }
  this.elements = q.slice(0, this.capacity);
};

function Node(location, axis, subnodes, datum) {
  this.location = location;
  this.axis = axis;
  this.subnodes = subnodes;  // = children nodes = [left child, right child]
  this.datum = datum;
};

Node.prototype.toArray = function() {
  var array = [
    this.location, 
    this.subnodes[0] ? this.subnodes[0].toArray() : null, 
    this.subnodes[0] ? this.subnodes[1].toArray() : null
  ];
  array.axis = this.axis;
  return array;
};

Node.prototype.flatten = function() {
  var left = this.subnodes[0] ? this.subnodes[0].flatten() : null,
      right = this.subnodes[1] ? this.subnodes[1].flatten() : null;
  return left && right ? [this].concat(left, right) :
        left ? [this].concat(left) :
        right ? [this].concat(right) :
        [this];
};

// k-NN search
Node.prototype.find = function(target, k) {
  k = k || 1;
  
  var queue = new BPQ(k),
      scannedNodes = [];
  
  search(this);
  
  return {
    nearestNodes: queue.values,
    scannedNodes: scannedNodes,
    maxDistance: queue.maxPriority()
  };
  
  // 1-NN algorithm outlined here:
  // http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/handouts/assignment-3-kdtree.pdf
  function search(node) {
    if (node === null) return;
    
    scannedNodes.push(node);
    
    queue.add(node, distance(node.location, target));

    if (target[node.axis] < node.location[node.axis]) {
      search(node.subnodes[0]);
      var otherNode = node.subnodes[1];
    } else {
      search(node.subnodes[1]);
      var otherNode = node.subnodes[0];
    }

    var delta = Math.abs(node.location[node.axis] - target[node.axis]);
    if (!queue.isFull() || delta < queue.maxPriority()) {
      search(otherNode);
    }
  }
};

Node.prototype.lines = function(extent) {
  var x0 = extent[0][0], 
      y0 = extent[0][1],
      x1 = extent[1][0], 
      y1 = extent[1][1],
      x = this.location[0],
      y = this.location[1];
    
  if (this.axis == 0) {
    var line = [[x, y0], [x, y1]];
    var left = this.subnodes[0] ?
      this.subnodes[0].lines([[x0, y0], [x, y1]]) : null;
    var right = this.subnodes[1] ?
      this.subnodes[1].lines([[x, y0], [x1, y1]]) : null;
  } 
  else if (this.axis == 1) {
    var line = [[x0, y], [x1, y]];
    var left = this.subnodes[0] ?
      this.subnodes[0].lines([[x0, y0], [x1, y]]) : null;
    var right = this.subnodes[1] ?
      this.subnodes[1].lines([[x0, y], [x1, y1]]) : null;
  }
  
  return left && right ? [line].concat(left, right) :
        left ? [line].concat(left) :
        right ? [line].concat(right) :
        [line];
}

function KDTree() {
  var x = function(d) { return d[0]; },
      y = function(d) { return d[1]; };
  
  function tree(data) {
    var points = data.map(function(d) { 
      var point = [x(d), y(d)];
      point.datum = d;
      return point; 
    });
    
    return treeify(points, 0);
  }
  
  tree.x = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return x;
    x = _;
    return tree;
  };
  
  tree.y = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return y;
    y = _;
    return tree;
  };
  
  return tree;
  
  // Adapted from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree
  function treeify(points, depth) {
      try { var k = points[0].length; }
      catch (e) { return null; }

      var axis = depth % k;
      
      points.sort(function(a, b) { return a[axis] - b[axis]; });
      i_median = Math.floor(points.length / 2);
      
      var point = points[i_median],
          left_points = points.slice(0, i_median),
          right_points = points.slice(i_median + 1);
          
      return new Node(
        point,
        axis,
        [treeify(left_points, depth + 1), treeify(right_points, depth + 1)],
        point.datum
      );
    }
}

function min(array, accessor) {
  return array
    .map(function(d) { return accessor(d); })
    .reduce(function(a, b) { return a < b ? a : b; });
}

function max(array, accessor) {
  return array
    .map(function(d) { return accessor(d); })
    .reduce(function(a, b) { return a > b ? a : b; });
}

function get(key) { return function(d) { return d[key]; }; }

function distance(p0, p1) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1[0] - p0[0], 2) + Math.pow(p1[1] - p0[1], 2));
}

/// example usage


var width = 700,
   height = 175;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var data = d3.range(2000)
.map(function() {
  return {
    x: width * Math.random(),
    y: height * Math.random(),
    value: Math.random() // just for testing purposes
  };
});

var tree = KDTree()
  .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
  .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
  (data);

svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "lines")
   .selectAll(".line").data(tree.lines([[0,0], [width, height]]))
   .enter()
   .append("path")
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("d", d3.line());

var points = svg.append("g").attr("class", "points")
    .selectAll(".point").data(tree.flatten())
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.location[0]; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.location[1]; })
    .attr("r", 4);

var halo = svg.append("circle").attr("class", "halo");

update([width/3, height/2]);

svg.append("rect").attr("class", "event-canvas")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
  .on("mousemove", function() { update(d3.mouse(this)); });

function update(target) {
    var nearest = tree.find(target, 10);

    points
      .classed("scanned", function(d) { return nearest.scannedNodes.indexOf(d) !== -1; })
      .classed("selected", function(d) { return nearest.nearestNodes.indexOf(d) !== -1; });

    halo
      .attr("cx", target[0])
      .attr("cy", target[1])
      .attr("r", nearest.maxDistance);
  }
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
}

.point {
  fill: #999;
  stroke: #fff;
}

.point.scanned {
  fill: orange;
  stroke: #999;
}

.point.selected {
  fill: red;
  stroke: #999;
}

.halo {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Оптимально? Для множественных запросов?

1. Построить диаграмму Вороного на исходном наборе точек
2. Решить задачу попадания тестовой точки в многоугольник диаграммы Вороного каким-нибудь алгоритмом [point location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location).

Такой подход будет сразу давать ближайшую точку.