# Граница видимости и граница холста

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Такой вопрос: допустим у нас есть некоторая локация, в которой сможет передвигаться игрок, она большая, но заранее известно, какие объекты в каких местах на ней находятся. 
Есть игрок, мы видим вокруг игрока в определенном радиусе, а то что за радиусом видимости мы не видим.
Вопрос в том, как это реализовать на canvas.
До этого, как я раньше делал, все видимые объекты сразу же рисовались на видимом поле.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Простейший способ - считать `bounding box` объекта и перед отрисовкой проверять попал ли он на экран, попробуйте поиграть с количеством точек в этом примере, чтобы найти предел производительности Вашего компьютера, тогда можно будет понять как эта оптимизация влияет на производительность

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var width, height;
var canvas = d3.select("canvas").call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoom));
resize();
var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");
var randomX = d3.randomNormal(width / 2, 80);
var randomY = d3.randomNormal(height / 2, 80);
var data = d3.range(1e4).map(function() { 
    return [randomX(), randomY()]; 
});
let r1 = 1;
var transform = {x:0, y:0, k:1};

draw();

function zoom() {
  transform = d3.event.transform;
  context.save();
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.translate(transform.x, transform.y);
  context.scale(transform.k, transform.k);
  draw();
  context.restore();
}

function draw() {
  var i = -1, n = data.length, d, c=0;
  context.beginPath();
  let rect = visibleRect();
  
    context.beginPath()
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  while (++i < n) {
    d = data[i];
    
    if (inScreen(d, rect)) {
      c++;
      context.moveTo(d[0], d[1]);
      context.arc(d[0], d[1], r1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    }
  }
  context.fill();
  log.textContent = 'кругов нарисовано: ' + c + ', используйте drag и wheel'
}

function resize() {
  width = canvas.node().width = window.innerWidth;
  height = canvas.node().height = window.innerHeight-22;
}

function visibleRect() {
  let pad = 50;
  let x = transform.x-pad, 
      y = transform.y-pad, 
      k = transform.k,
      w = width-pad*2,
      h = height-pad*2;
      
  context.beginPath()
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)';
  context.rect(-x/k, -y/k, w/k, h/k);
  context.fill();
  return [-x/k, -y/k, w/k-x/k, h/k-y/k]
}

function inScreen(d, r) {
  return d[0] > r[0]-r1 && d[1] > r[1]-r1 && d[0]<r[2]+r1 && d[1]<r[3]+r1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin:0;overflow:hidden">
<canvas></canvas>
<div id="log"></div>
</body>
```

Недостаток такого подхода - перебор всех элементов, чтобы этого избежать придется использовать структуры данных - например [квадродерево](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/963790/188366)